# Add(sum) into column value rather than Updating/replacing existing value

Tags: c#, sql, database, datatable

I want that in a DataBase i have column with values in it let's say that column has 20 in specified cell then in update Query i provide it with 10 then cell should be Updated with 30 rather then 10. 
Still i have wrote upto this code below.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < newDt.Rows.Count;i++ )
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("update batch set sold_qty=@soldqty2 where id=@id2",con);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@soldqty2", Convert.ToInt32(newDt.Rows[i]["QTY"]));
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id2", Convert.ToInt32(newDt.Rows[i]["BATCH NUM"]));


            rexe=command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for `+`:

```
update batch
    set sold_qty = sold_qty + @soldqty2
    where id = @id2;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Exactly i want to do that. You solved my Problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
for (int i = 0; i < newDt.Rows.Count;i++ )
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("update batch set sold_qty=@soldqty2 where id=@id2",con);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@soldqty2", Convert.ToInt32(newDt.Rows[i]["QTY"]));
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id2", Convert.ToInt32(newDt.Rows[i]["QTY"]) + Convert.ToInt32(newDt.Rows[i]["BATCH NUM"]));


        rexe=command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

Comment: It is not what i want to do, i want to basically is that add in already value present in database colum. For Example if in Database column 20 is stored when i run update query with 10, then value in database should become 30.